# how and where to add CSS style in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

SharePoint 2010 is upgraded to SharePoint 2013 and the problem I see the font-szie is very big. I checked and compared ms-vb class should have font-size 8 and font-type : verdana, arial etc.

Where can I add these 2 properties in my site? I don't have access to the " _layout/15/1033/ " folder.
I don't want to create for everypage a contenteditor and adding a style.

Where can I add these the styles then? I do have access to the site via SharePoint Designer 2013.

The change should only affect the site collection and the sites within... not the parent sites.

```
.ms-vb   or td.ms-vb
{
font-size: 8pt;
font-style: "verdana, arial";
}
```

NOTE: I may not update Masterpage (no rights). There are many site collections and different people are responsible for it. I'm just responsible for my site collection with 160 subsites. So is there a way to add a CSS class in somewhere for ONCE and get ONLY my site collection be affected?

in otherwords, is there a place to CSS class or file that only affects the current site colleciton? or in another words is there a CSS at SITE collection level. (current site collection)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the security rights to create or edit the site masterpage, you can add a style element that will be applied to all pages in that site, or even better, link to a new CSS file you create in the Style Library.

EDIT: if you don't have the ability to edit a masterpage, you can "Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it" in the Site Master Page Settings under Alternate CSS URL.

/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx

Comment: no rights to masterpage... it's in SP2013. where can I put my CSS code in SP2013?

Comment: Updated for non-masterpage access

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new style sheet or add an override within the existing style.css located in _catalogs/masterpage/style.css. Then reference this from the masterPage. Or if you want to be bad, add the script element directly in the MP

```
<script>
    .ms-vb or td.ms-vb
    {
      font-size: 8pt !important;
      font-style: "verdana, arial" !important;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I can't  update master page... any other places you advice? SEE my note I just added above again.

Comment: where is that file? which folder? I'm using SP2013.

Comment: I put the path in the answer. It should be in the same folder as the MP